# How do I reload the time zone information during runtime in Busybox/Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, embedded-linux, busybox

I want to set different time zone during run time and so I am setting /etc/timezone file but TZ environment variable is not reflecting. There are applications depends on TZ variable, for example date command is set based on TZ variable. So I have to set the both /etc/timezone file and TZ variable to reload new time zone.

I tried few ways and one of the method like,

exporting TZ variable in ~/.profile and source ~/.profile from reload time zone script and no luck.

How to reload TZ environment variable permanently from /etc/timezone in busybox during runtime (without reboot or without logout)?

Comment: The timezone handling actually depends on the libc you are using. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, TZ is an environment variable. All processes already started with an environment containing a different value for TZ will not be affected by anything, unless those processes have explicit means for that.

Apart from that, for your current shell, exporting TZ should actually do the trick for all processes started from your shell.